# Is it possible to transfer a condition into a condition only depends on $A,B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Let $\alpha\in(0,\pi/2)$.

Is it possible to transfer the following condition into a condition only depends on $A,B$?

$A\sin\alpha+2B\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}<0$ when $A\cos\alpha+B\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}=0$

Comment: Do you know how to express $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ in terms of $\sin (x/2)$ and $\cos(x/2)$?

Comment: Note that
$$
\cos(\alpha) = 2\cos^2 (\alpha/2) - 1.
$$
With that, your equation can be solved for $\cos \alpha$ in terms of $A$ and $B$. From there, the fact that $\sin (\alpha/2) > 0$ means that
$$
\sin(\alpha/2) = \sqrt{1 - \cos^2 (\alpha/2)}, \quad \sin(\alpha) = 2 \sin(\alpha/2)\cos(\alpha/2).
$$

Comment: As an intuitive perspective of why, as the previous comments indicate, relations between $~\sin(\alpha), ~\cos(\alpha)~$ and $~\sin(\alpha/2), ~\cos(\alpha/2) ~$ need to be examined,   consider that $~\cos(\alpha) - \sin(\alpha),~$ must be **compared** with $~\cos(\alpha/2) - \sin(\alpha/2).$

Comment: @BenGrossmann  Thank you! This would give $3B\pm \sqrt{B^2+8A^2}<0$. But from another deduction, it seems $A\sin\alpha+2B\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}<0$ is always true as long as $B>0$: Since $A\cos\alpha+B\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}=0$, we have $A=-\frac{B\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}}{\cos\alpha}$. Plug $A$ into the inequality gives $B(-\frac{\cos{(\alpha/2)}\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}+2\sin(\alpha/2))<0$. Since $(-\frac{\cos{(\alpha/2)}\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}+2\sin(\alpha/2))<0$ for all $\alpha\in(0,\pi/2]$, we need $B>0$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann What I meant is this two deductions, which seems hold sufficient and necessary to the original condition, but they are not equivalent.